# Implicit renormalization of $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

In the lecture notes, I am following on Quantum Field Theory, we want to renormalize $\phi^4$ theory with the Lagrangian:
$$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \phi^0)^2 - \frac{1}{2} m_0^2 (\phi^0)^2 - g_0(\phi^0)^4$$
We have already done this before through explicit renormalization by redefining the bare coupling constants (which have a $0$ attached) in terms of a normalization factor and a finite quantity. For example $m_0^2 = Z_{m^2} m^2$. However, now the aim is to define the renormalization group flow. For this, they want to give a more abstract definition. Specifically, they define the following:
$$Z^{-1}(m_0^2, g_0, \mu) = \frac{d}{dp^2}\left[-i \Gamma^{(2)}(p^2, m_0^2, g_0)\right]^{-1}|_{p^2=\mu^2}$$
Where $\Gamma^{(2)}$ denotes the two point function. Then, they use this to define the renormalized field as $\phi_0 = \sqrt{Z}\phi$. Now, to fix $m_0^2$ and $g_0$ they use the condition that the renormalized quantities $m(\mu)$ and $g(\mu)$ should be finite, where these have been defined by:
$$m^2(\mu) = Z(m_0^2, g_0, \mu) [-i \Gamma^{(2)}(p^2, m_0^2, g_0)]^{-1} |_{p^2 = \mu^2}$$
and
$$g(\mu) = Z^2(m_0^2, g_0, \mu) [-i \hat\Gamma^{(4)}(p^2_i, m_0^2, g_0)]^{-1} |_{\text{symmetric } \mu^2 \text{ point}},$$
where $\hat\Gamma^{(4)}$ denotes the 1 propagator irreducible version 4-point function.

However, these definitions are not really motivated by the lecture notes. They simply state that this is an abstracted version of what they did before in the explicit renormalization only that this way of doing things is nicer as we now only have a single renormalization constant instead of renormalizing each constant individually. In addition, this view is better for understanding the renormalization group. However, I do not see how the above implicit procedure is the same as the explicit procedure from before.

In addition, I do not understand how the above definitions are sensible. Why do we want the normalization constant for the fields to be this specific derivative of the 2-point function? Why define the renormalized coupling constants in the above way? I do not see how I could have arrived at these definition on my own.